# Configuration Issue for IBM Filenet 5.2

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet-content-engine

I installed IBM Filenet Content Engine 5.2,on my machine.I am getting problem while configuring GCD datasources for new profile.
Let me first explain the setps I did,then I would mention the problem that I am getting.
First,I created GCD database in DB2,then I created datasources required for configuration of profile in WAS Admin Console.I created J2C Authentication Alias,for user which has access to GCD database and configured it with datasources.I am getting test database connection as successful but when I run task of configuring GCD datasources,it fails with the following error:-

```
Starting to run Configure GCD JDBC Data Sources

Configure GCD JDBC Data Sources ******
Finished running Configure GCD JDBC Data Sources
An error occurred while running Configure GCD JDBC Data Sources
Running the task failed with the following message: The data source configuration failed: 
WASX7209I: Connected to process "server1" on node Poonam-PcNode01 using SOAP connector;  The type of process is: UnManagedProcess
testing Database connection
DSRA8040I: Failed to connect to the DataSource.  Encountered java.sql.SQLException: [jcc][t4][2013][11249][3.62.56] Connection authorization failure occurred.  Reason: User ID or Password invalid. ERRORCODE=-4214, SQLSTATE=28000 DSRA0010E: SQL State = 28000, Error Code = -4,214.
```

It looks like simple error of user id and password not valid.I am using same alias for other datasources as well and they are working fine.so not sure,why I am getting error.I have also tried changing scope of datasources,but no success.Can somebody please help?

Answer (score 0):

running "FileNet Configuration Manager" task of configuring GCD datasources will create all the needs things in WAS (including Alias), do not created it before manually. 
I suspect it had an issue with exciting JDBC data sources/different names Alias

Answer (score 0):

Seems from your message that you are running it from Filene configuration manager. Could you please double check from your database whether user id is authorised to execute query in GCD database. It is definitely do it with permission issue.